# What is the difference between: t = a and t = [...a] when a is an array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand if there is any difference between these two methods for copying an array?

```
 let a = [1,2,3,4];
 t = a; // -> t = [1,2,3,4]
 t = [...a] // -> t = [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Hint: one of these is *not* a "method for copying an array". Try running `a[0] = 5; alert(t)` after each version, and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first, `t = a`, means that the array that `t` references is the *same array* as `a`. If `a` is changed, `t` will be changed as well:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
t = a;
a.push(10);
console.log(t);
```

The second, `t = [...a]`, means that `t` is now a *new array* which contains every item that was in the original array. Subsequent changes to the old array will not affect `t`:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
t = [...a];
a.push(10);
console.log(t);
```

Note that this is only in respect to mutations of the original `a` array. If the items that `a` initially contains are *objects*, then those objects will not be deep-copied when `t` is created - there will still be only one object in memory for each item in the original array. So, mutations to any of those objects in the original array will be seen as affecting `t`, even if `t` is a new array:

```js
const a = [{ prop: 'val', prop2: 'val2' }];
const t = [...a];
a[0].anotherProp = 'anotherVal';
console.log(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

Main difference is that when you use `...` spread operator, you actually  share a shallow copy of `a` array. That means `a` becomes immutable and a  new array is passed with new reference pointer in memory to `t`.

When you simply copy, i.e. `t=a`, you share a reference pointer in memory. So whenever you change contents of `t`, it automatically updates `a` also.

Answer (score 0):

> `let t = a;  // assigning reference to t`

The first method is just assigning the `reference` of a to t, which means if you change the value at either `a` or `t`, it will affect both `a` and `t` as they are pointing to the same memory location

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4];
let t = a;

a[0] = 120

console.log(a)
console.log(t)
```

> ```
> let t = [...a];         // creating a shallow copy of a and assign it to t
> ```

Where's second method makes a shallow copy and assign it to

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4];
let t = [...a];

a[0] = 120

console.log(a)
console.log(t)
```